# How to find the port where kibana is running?

Tags: elasticsearch, port, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have Elastic Stack set up in on-prem servers. It is runnnig fine and querying data is possible without any issue. How can I find the port where kibana is running?

Comment: The default kibana port is 5601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use netstat command to view all the ports that are being used in the system. If not exists, install using `sudo apt install net-tools`.

Type in `netstat -tnlp`. Provide sudo to get which ports are used by different programs.

Kibana is a node server. So search for `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep node`.

Answer (score 0):

Default port is 5601. It can be configured in kibana.yml, option setup.port

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

Comment: Hi, I haven't set "setup.port" in kibana.yml. And the documentation doesn't show any "setup.port"

Comment: Thanks. But that kine is currently commented. Still port is 5601 as per the accepted answer.

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa Right. You need to uncomment it and set the desired port number, if you need to change it. Otherwise you don’t need to change it, it will keep default value of 5601.